# How can I click multiple buttons with Selenium driver?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have an email button, on which I click and see the email of the person:

[image]

I want to either click all of them at the same time if possible or one by one.
I have tried the following but it only click the first one and that is it. Should I maybe close this one before clicking the new one?

```
email_buttons_xpath = '//[@id="contactFinderActions65b56ac9815cbc00012c48f3"]/div/div/button[1]'

email_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, email_buttons_xpath)

for email_button in email_buttons:
    email_button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you have to close the opened window in order to open the same window but for the next row, otherwise your 'next row' click will be intercepted by the already opened modal window. You cannot open this 'email info' for all rows at the same time.

So, you just have to add one more click at the end of your 'for' loop.

But also, consider the following:

- make sure your xpath is valid, and it returns the required number of elements (numbers in IDs are likely to be dynamic).
- wait for the element(s) to be visible/clickable/present before interacting with it(them). See [expected_conditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html)
- After closing the opened modal window, use the same expected conditions to ensure that the window is closed before doing the next click. Sometimes Selenium can be really fast, so it is always better to wait.